# how to generate arrays automatically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make a loop that makes arrays automatically and assign the values to it.
The problem is how to generate the array itself automatically.

```
for(var attGetter=1; attGetter <= num; attGetter++){
    var catesArray1 = new Array();

    for(var atttGetterArray=1; atttGetterArray <= series; attGetterArray++){
        idOfInput  = "cate"+chartGetter+"_series"+attGetterArray;
        catesArray1.push($("#"+idOfInput).val());
    }
}
```

I want the loop to generate the array itself automatically like
catesArray1
catesArray2
catesArray3

and so on..

Comment: `if` is not a loop. Don't try to generate variables called `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, ...; use an array `foo[i]` instead.

Comment: Whether the arrays are in global namespace

Comment: You need a two dimentional array or you want to generate array in variables

Comment: @melpomene, sorry I wrote `if` mistakenly.

Comment: You should use a 2D array but if there is no way to use it you can try  my fiddle from my answer http://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/KudTe/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an object or an array to hold the multiple arrays you wish to create. Maybe something you are looking for is like the following?

```
var arrayHolder = new Array();

  for(var attGetter=1; attGetter <= num; attGetter++){
  var catesArray = new Array();

  for(var attGetterArray=1; atttGetterArray <= series; attGetterArray++){
    idOfInput  = "cate"+chartGetter+"_series"+attGetterArray;
    catesArray.push($("#"+idOfInput).val());
  }
  arrayHolder.push(catesArray);
}
```

Comment: so the only choice is to make two-dimensional array. I can't to find another way to auto-generate arrays

Comment: You cannot create new arrays referenced by names with the value of your loop counter if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes you can see this http://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/KudTe/2/ you can create them using eval

Comment: @Farrukh Subhani, I also just read this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) about why you have to be careful doing that...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the arrays to be in global namespace, You can try

```
window['catesArray' + attGetter] = [];
...
window['catesArray' + attGetter].push(...)
```

Else you can create a hash object and use it to hold the reference

```
var obj = {};
.....
obj['catesArray' + attGetter] = [];
.....
obj['catesArray' + attGetter].push(...)
```

Comment: Yes, again there are multiple answers which deals with solving the problem using two dimensional arrays. It is another way to solve the problem by using dynamic variables

Answer (score 1):

In that case you will have to create one new array that holds all the `cacatesArray`s from first `for` loop

```
var catesArrayContainer = new Array(); //<<<---------------------
for(var attGetter=1; attGetter <= num; attGetter++){
    var catesArray = new Array();

    for(var atttGetterArray=1; atttGetterArray <= series; attGetterArray++){
        idOfInput  = "cate"+chartGetter+"_series"+attGetterArray;
        catesArray.push($("#"+idOfInput).val());
    }
    catesArrayContainer.push(catesArray); //<<<--------------------
}
```

**EDIT :**

This happens because the scope of variable `catesArray1` was limited. When the loop enters next iteration the `catesArray1` gets reinitialized, thus losing all the previously stored values...
Now in the code I have posted, we are storing every instance of `catesArray1` in another array, and your values persist out side of the `for` loop

Comment: so the only choice is to make two-dimensional array. I can't to find another way to auto-generate arrays

Comment: As someone reminded me, the scope of catesArray1 is not limited to the for loop, but you are absolutely right about it being reinitialized and losing it's values

Comment: That depends, What do you want to achieve exactly?
From the question you have posted, using `2D array` sounds perfect solution

Comment: @KyleWeller : Yes, It has `function` scope... But since OP hasn't specified the exact location of the code, I answered considering the `js` file only contains the code in the question.

Comment: also : understand this... in `this` particular case, the scope of `catesArray` `IS` limited to for lopp.. Why? because, it has been declared with `var`... If `var` wasn't there, then it'd have been accessible from outside of that for loop..

Comment: variables declared with `var` have block scope... if the variable is not declared using `var` then it is treated as `global`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this for 4 arrays of 5 elements each

```
yourarray=[];
for (i = 0; i <4; i++) {
     temparray=[];
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        temparray.push($('#'+whateverID+'_'+i+'_'+j)) //your values here
    }
yourarray.push(temparray);
}
```

Check it on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/KudTe/). open chrome console to see array

**If you want to create array within loop from index**

You can use eval to evaluate javascript from strings but i wont use that unless there is no other way. you can see both above and eval method in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/KudTe/2/). Open Chrome console to see array values
**Just a comparison of using eval and 2D array**
Open console in chrome while you run this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farrukhsubhani/KudTe/4/) and you will see the difference in eval and 2darray in context of this question.

Comment: sorry had to change it a lot from an app to make it simple

Answer (score 0):

You should assign them to an object. In this case, make an object variable before the first for-loop to hold all arrays:

```
var allArrays = {};

for(var attGetter=1; attGetter <= num; attGetter++){
    var currentArray = allArrays['catesArray' + attGetter] = new Array();

    for(var atttGetterArray=1; atttGetterArray <= series; attGetterArray++){
        idOfInput  = "cate"+chartGetter+"_series"+attGetterArray;
        currentArray.push($("#"+idOfInput).val());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting to create & allocate dynamically named variables, I would think of this more of an `array` of `array`'s if you will. In other words, create an array that holds all of the arrays you want:

```
var collections = []; // Literal notation for creating an array in JS
```

From here, it's a matter of making each value you create within this array its own array:

```
var n = 10; // Total amount of arrays you want
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var values = [];
    // Have another loop that fills in the values array as expected
    collections.push(values); // Each element at collections[i] is its own array.
}
```

If you truly need named elements, you could potentially do something very similar with just an object `{}` instead, and refer to each element by a name you create.

```
var collections = {}; // Literal notation for an object in JS
var n = 10; // Total amount of arrays you want
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var values = []; // Literal notation for an array in JS
    // Fill in the values array as desired

    var name = 'arr' + i; // How you'll refer to it in the object
    collections[name] = values;
}
```

I suggest the former though, since it does not sound like you need to have explicit names on your arrays, but just want multiple layers of arrays.